# Bibitem complex structure

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is there any link, info or documentation how should be every entry in the **\bibitem** mentioned? For example

```
\bibitem{Misiak} A. Misiak. \ \textit{$n$-inner product spaces.} Math.Nachr. {\bf 140} (1989), 299--319.

\bibitem{WKG} R.A. Wibawa-Kusumah and H. Gunawan. \textit{Two equivalent $n$-norms on the space of $p$-summable sequences}. To appear in {\it Period. Math. Hungar}.

\bibitem{ksw} P. Kostyrko, T. \v{S}al\'{a}t and W. Wilczy\'nski, $\mathcal{I}$-convergence, \emph{Real Anal. Exchange} \textbf{26(2)} (2000-2001), 669--686.
```

This bibitems can contains many entries (author, authortype, editor, editortype, editorX, editorXtype, holder, bookauthor ...). From this three examples I can extract without problem maybe **numeric parts** and assume they belong to **pages** or **section** entry. But when I found many different methods of storing info about for example: **authors**, I'm quite undecided how should I write **bibliography cutter to entries** efficiently:

```
jean de la fontaine
Jean de la fontaine
Jean {de} la fontaine
jean {de} {la} fontaine
Jean {de} {la} fontaine
Jean De La Fontaine
jean De la Fontaine
Jean de La Fontaine
```

This is the case when **\bibitem** contains only one author, but there is also cases that it could contains even more. How could I logical extract bibliography entries? Is there anywhere complex structure mentioned?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question. I would suggest to store your bibliographic information in a database in the BibTeX-format. You say which style to use, and LaTeX and an auxiliary Program (biber/bibtex) do the rest.

Comment: This has also been posted on [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=25206&p=85719#p85718).

Comment: I forgot to mention @Johannes_B, that my task is to extract bibitems from **.tex file** with Java 1.7 and I can't use Tex processor or any other ,,help hand". I need to write tex commands parser and **bibitem entries cutter**.

Comment: We just had a similar question: [LaTeX to BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/476721)

Comment: There is a multitude of well-established "bibliography styles" that determine how a bibliographic entry in a bib file should be typeset, i.e., how the information in a given entry is to be transformed into a `\bibitem`.  Much meta-information is dropped in the process of going from an entry in a bib file to a `\bibitem`. What exactly are you trying to achieve by parsing a `\bibitem` (which, by construction, is missing almost all meta information)?

Comment: Let's say, that I use first mentioned bibitem: \bibitem{Misiak} A. Misiak. \ \textit{$n$-inner product spaces.} Math.Nachr. {\bf 140} (1989), 299--319. . I need programmatically to extract authors, title, pages, volume and other entries and detect that this bibitem is the type: article or book or whatever.

Comment: Have a look in the above linked Q/A. If all entries are of the same type and typeset in exactly the same way, easy peasy, RegExp. But if there are different types (meaning different order/formatting) it will be very hard. I guess you can teach the algorithm, but this might take some time.

Comment: See also the posting [Convert .bbl file to .bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203177/5001).