# Changing thebibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm editing a book written by multiple authors. We ha agreed on formatting the bibliography using bibtex with the style \bibliographystyle{spmpsci}.
However, some of the authors used the thebibliography environment directly in the main file.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{frag}
G.~Aggarwal, M.~Bawa, P.~Ganesan, H.~Garcia-Molina, K.~Kenthapadi, R.~Motwani,
U.~Srivastava, D.~Thomas, and Y.~Xu.
\newblock Two can keep a secret: {A} distributed architecture for secure
  database services.
\newblock In {\em Proc. of CIDR 2005}, Asilomar, CA, USA, January 2005.
\end{thebibliography}{10}
```

I can't find a way to change the bibliography style of the references produced by thebibliography (they are stet in style "plain").

I tried to add the comman \bibliographystyle{spmpsci} before the beginning of thebibliography environment and it clearly doesn't work (I really did'nt think it would have, but who knows). I read through the documentation and around the internet but couldn't find anything really helpful.

Am I missing something really easy? Is it possible at all? or I should lose hope and devote half a day to rewrite the bibitems into a bibtex file?

Any input will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does changing the 10 to Xyz12 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to save the contents of `thebibliography` into a `.bbl` fikem convert the bibliography to bib using one of the methods listed here [Convert .bbl file to .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203177/convert-bbl-file-to-bib-file), (I especially like http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/) and then reprocess with bibtex.  It is a cumbersome process, but you are trying to recreate a cow from steaks...

Comment: Thanks! I already saved the thebibliography entries into a bbl but wasn't able to find a way to convert them back to a bib file.The link you provided is precious!