# How to convert contents of a 'thebibliography' environment into a bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, convert

In my Latex document, I have the bibliography included in the text as:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{item1} citation1 
\bibitem{item2} citation2 
.
.
.
\end{thebibliography}
```

I want to specify this bibliography as a `.bib` file. My attempt is I copy past the:

```
\bibitem{item1} citation1 
\bibitem{item2} citation2
.
.
.
```

in a `.tex` file; for the next step, I want to convert it to a `.bib` file. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you seen the posting [Convert .bbl file to .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203177/5001)? It mentions porting information from a .bbl file to a .bib file. However, the underlying idea is the same as with porting information from a `thebibliography` environment to a .bib file.

Comment: @Mico So this means that I need to do that manually?

Comment: There is a script, you could try. You'll have to register, though. Should be free, though: https://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/

Comment: This answer might be of help, too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476997/220875

Comment: @walid - See also [Changing thebibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233655/5001) and, in particular, [@Boris's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233662/5001).

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot! That was helpful :) I succeded to convert it using http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/

Comment: @phil-elkabat thank you