# convert bibitem in .bib or .bbl

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have an article where the bibliography is written with a list of \bibitem items. I would like to merge this bibliography with my personnal bibliography which is under the form biblio.bib

Anyone has an idea? I have seen a lot of posts to go the other way around but none in this direction.

One way to do that would be to have a .bbl file because then I could import it in Bibdesk, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233442/35864, unfrtunately the tool now needs registration. I tested it a while back and it worked reasonably well. Of course you will have to double check the produced `.bib` file and should expect some manual corrections and interventions to be necessary. I also think I read about a similar tool on CTAN a while ago, but I seem to remember that the results weren't that impressive.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203177/35864 (but without an answer mentioning `text2bib` - there is only a comment).