# Use only some entries of a bbl file?

Tags: bibliographies, bbl

I have a big .bbl file which [I cannot easily convert to a .bib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203177/convert-bbl-file-to-bib-file).

Inside a new .tex file, I would like to use (cite) only few entries of the .bbl file with the help of `\cite` command and the label (present in the bbl).

Is it possible?

**Precision:** In fact, I have 300+ .tex file which contain each some references (called with `\cite`). There was a .bib at the origin but I have only access to the .bbl now. The .bbl contains several hundred of reference; this is why it is not really an option to copy/paste the references needed.

Here is a sample of the .bbl

```
\begin{thebibliography}{396}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
\input{babelbst.tex}
\newcommand{\Capitalize}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
\newcommand{\capitalize}[1]{\expandafter\Capitalize#1}


\bibitem[{Bruns(1888)}]{BruH1888}
Bruns, H.
\newblock {\"Uber die Integrale des Vielk\"orper-Problems}.
\newblock \emph{Acta mathematica} 11,  1888, 25--96.


\bibitem[{G\'erard \bbletal{}(1972)G\'erard, Reeb \bbletal{}}]{PaiP1972a}
G\'erard, R., Reeb, G., \bbland{} Sec, A., \bbleds{}.
\newblock \emph{{{\OE}uvres de Paul Painlev\'e, Volume 1}}.
\newblock Paris: CNRS, 1972.

\bibitem[{G\'erard \bbletal{}(1974)G\'erard, Reeb \bbletal{}}]{PaiP1974}
---.
\newblock \emph{{{\OE}uvres de Paul Painlev\'e, Volume 2}}.
\newblock Paris: CNRS, 1974.

\bibitem[{G\'erard \bbletal{}(1975)G\'erard, Reeb \bbletal{}}]{PaiP1975}
---.
\newblock \emph{{{\OE}uvres de Paul Painlev\'e, Volume 3: \'Equations
  diff\'erentielles du second ordre}}.
\newblock Paris: CNRS, 1975.
.
.
.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: You have not given much information,  But in most bbl markup you should be able to simply delete  the entries that you do not use. It is unusual to have a `.bbl` file not generated by bibtex, is there really no `.bib` source available? (hand written bibliographies have no reason to use that `.bbl` extension.)

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` as suggested by the tags? It would be possibly to some limited degree to make use of a pre-existing `.bbl` file (assuming `refcontext`s and `refsection`s match), but that is very fragile and crucially relies on the `.bbl` version matching with your `biblatex` version. Since the `.bbl` may contain additional (variable) information not present in the `.bib` (for disambiguation, mainly) it can not be guaranteed that things will look alright when you only select a subset of the entries and ignore the rest.

Comment: It would help if you could share more details about your `.bbl` file, your general setup and what you have in mind.

Comment: This `.bbl` file was created by BibTeX for standard `thebibliography` inclusion and is therefore completely incompatible with `biblatex`. Do you want to use it with `biblatex`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for the lack of informations. I updated my question. Deleting unused entries is not a option because of the number of total entries.

Comment: @moewe In fact, I plan at the end to use pandoc to convert the tex file to html pages. Sorry for the missleading "biblatex" tag, I was thinking maybe biblatex offers a solution.

Comment: A LaTeX-based solution seems tricky. `thebibliography` is basically a list and `\bibitem` is `\item`. You would have to tell LaTeX to skip certain items based on their key. I'm not aware of a simple way to do that in the normal set-up. It might be easier to write a script to pre-process the `.bbl` file and throw out all keys you don't need.  This is still potentially problematic if you have two works "Smith 2000a" and "Smith 2000b" and throw out "Smit 2000a", then only "Smith 2000b" will remain, but then it should become "Smith 2000"...

Comment: I would have thought it would be a simple job to just use an editor or perl or whatever, just run latex without the bbl file so latex writes the citation keys to the aux file (which is what bibtex would use) then just extract that list of entries from the bbl file.